# Multithreading and multiprocessing for python tests of web-services

Tags: python, multithreading, web-services, multiprocessing, autotest

I have python class that contains several def's (>100). Each def contains one test. I'm trying to set up defs to multithreading / multiprocessing run. But it is unsuccessfully.

```
Class Method1(unittest.TestCase):
   def test1(self):
      #some test

   def test1(self):
      #some test

   ...

   def testN(self):
      #some test
```

How can I to set up this running?
Thanks!

Comment: Please specify which test framework you are using (unittest? nose? pytest?) and what is the command line and configuration you attempt to use to run the tests in parallel. Also, please improve the code example so it's valid Python ("class" instead of "Class") with some dummy code and `time.sleep` calls in your test methods so it's possible to verify whether it's running in parallel.

Comment: I use command line config: --mode=NameResourceForTesting -v. I have several .py Classes for the selected resource. Each Class contains several defs. The Class 'start.py' contains string 'if __name__ == "__main__":' and 'unittest.main()' in it.

Comment: Maybe must I to use nose?..

Comment: Nose supports running tests in parallel. Which test runner are you using if not nose?

Comment: This is unittest..